# SQL Server Complex Pivot Table Query

Tags: sql-server

My data is in the following format:

```
Customer_ID Order_ID Product_Sub-Category Product Name
=========== ======== ==================== ============
A00001      20001A   Vegetables           Onions
A00001      20001A   Vegetables           Garlic
A00002      20001B   Fruits               Apples
A00002      20001B   Fruits               Oranges
A00002      20001B   Vegetables           Spinach
A00003      20001C   Dairy                Milk
A00003      20001C   Dairy                Cheese
A00004      20001D   Meats                Lamb Chops
A00004      20001D   Meats                T-bone Steak
A00004      20001D   Dairy                Yoghurt
A00004      20001D   Fruits               Grapes
A00004      20001D   Vegetables           Garlic
```

I need to convert it into the format below.

```
Customer_ID Order_ID Vegetables     Fruits          Dairy        Meats
=========== ======== ==========     ======          =====        =====
A00001      20001A   Onions, Garlic
A00002      20001B   Spinach        Apples, Oranges 
A00003      20001C                                  Milk, Cheese    
A00004      20001D   Garlic         Grapes          Yoghurt      Lamb Chops, T-bone Steak
```

Please let me know if this can be done in a SQL Query

Comment: Sorry the formatting got messed up.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Yes, it's a pivot. What attempts have you made?

Comment: Boom - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx, next question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want or need to go dynamic.

> **EDIT - Added a Select Distinct for Performance**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Product_Sub-Category]) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Customer_ID],[Order_ID],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select A.Customer_ID
              ,A.Order_ID
              ,A.[Product_Sub-Category]
              ,C.String
         From  (Select Distinct Customer_ID,Order_ID,[Product_Sub-Category] From YourTable) A 
         Cross Apply (
                        Select String=Stuff((Select Distinct '','' +[Product Name] 
                                             From   YourTable 
                                             Where Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID 
                                               and Order_ID = A.Order_ID 
                                               and [Product_Sub-Category] = A.[Product_Sub-Category] 
                                             For XML Path ('''')),1,1,'''') 
                     ) C
       ) A
 Pivot (Max(String) For [Product_Sub-Category] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

If it helps, and if you don't need dynamic, the SQL generated is as follows

```
 Select [Customer_ID],[Order_ID],[Dairy],[Fruits],[Meats],[Vegetables]
  From (
        Select A.Customer_ID
              ,A.Order_ID
              ,A.[Product_Sub-Category]
              ,C.String
         From  (Select Distinct Customer_ID,Order_ID,[Product_Sub-Category] From YourTable) A 
         Cross Apply (
                        Select String=Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +[Product Name] 
                                              From  YourTable 
                                              Where Customer_ID=A.Customer_ID 
                                                and Order_ID=A.Order_ID 
                                                and [Product_Sub-Category]=A.[Product_Sub-Category] 
                                              For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
                     ) C
       ) A
 Pivot (Max(String) For [Product_Sub-Category] in ([Dairy],[Fruits],[Meats],[Vegetables]) ) p
```